# How would I solve $a-x\ln(x)-x=0$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried around 5 different approaches but I can’t isolate $x$ completely in any of them.

I got $e^{a}=e^{x}\cdot x^{x}$ but I can’t figure out how to isolate $x$ any further.

I also managed to get $\ln(x)=-1+\frac{a}{x}$ but I can't raise it all to the power of $e$ because of the $x$ in the denominator.

$\frac{x-a}{x}=\ln(x)$ also doesn't work because $x$ is still on both sides.

Please help with this.

Comment: Yeah you can't. You need to use numerical methods like Newton-Raphson or Fixed-point iteration. Is that a problem? Can you provide more context on the source of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make $x = e^y$ then

$$
a -e^y y-e^y = a-e^y(y+1)=0
$$

now making $u = y+1$ we follow with

$$
e a -ue^u=0
$$

at this point we can use the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) giving

$$
u = W(a e) = y + 1 = \ln x+1
$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, is to use the Wright $\omega$ function defined as the inverse of the function $f(x) = x \ln x$ :
$$\forall x > 0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}, y = x \ln x \iff x = \omega(y)$$

So for the equation :
$$a - x \ln x - x = 0$$
we have :
$$0 = a - x \ln x - x \ln e = a - x (\ln x + \ln e) = a - x \ln (x e)$$
then :
$$a e = (x e) \ln (x e) = f(x e)$$
We deduce that :
$$x e = \omega(a e)$$
Wich means :
$$x = \dfrac{\omega(a e)}{e}$$